# De-normalize data for t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I have a data set that has a 1 to many relationship ie: Contact info:

```
ContID  Country  Add1   Add2  City   ect...
001       USA     123  N/A   Blah
```

Above is the header record

The detail:

```
ContID  ContType  PhNum    Ext
001       FAX     11111   X222
001       BUSN    33333   X444
```

My end goal is to create new records that look like this:

```
ContID  Country Add1  Add2  City ContType1  ContType2  PhNum1  PhNum2  Ext1  Ext2        
001       USA    123  N/A   Blah   FAX        BUSN      11111    3333  x222  x444
```

I believe that there are a few way to accopmlish this for XML being one way and possibly a pivot being another.  I am not very good with `FOR XML` and I think this might be the best option.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to de-normalize your data?  You can often achieve requirements like this with other means.

Comment: The article here may help you understand why I have formatted your code to try to make it easier for others to assist you: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: yes this is due to normalizing and I am attempting to de-normalize this data.  Basically I am rebuilding some of the information in a database into a different format fo someone to use. by having the data normalized to this level will cause duplicated records down the line in some of my builds. I need to keep this 1 to 1 relationship to avoid this.

Comment: For the Detail table, is there is a variable number of records/ContType for each Contact, or are `FAX` and `BUSN` the only options?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple old fashioned query that will do the job for you see below:

```
/* Table declaractions and inserts for testing only, you will need to amend for 
 * your own structure.
 */

DECLARE @ContactInfo TABLE ( ContID int identity(1,1),
                             Country varchar(10), 
                             Add1 varchar(20),
                             Add2 varchar(20),
                             City varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @ContactInfo(Country, Add1, Add2, City)
VALUES ('USA','123','N/A','Blah')

DECLARE @ContactDetail TABLE ( ContID int,
                             ContType varchar(5), 
                             PhNum varchar(10),
                             Ext varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @ContactDetail(ContID, ContType, PhNum, Ext)
VALUES (1, 'Fax','11111','X1111')
INSERT INTO @ContactDetail(ContID, ContType, PhNum, Ext)
VALUES (1, 'Busn','22222','X2222')
INSERT INTO @ContactDetail(ContID, ContType, PhNum, Ext)
VALUES (1, 'Mobi','33333','X3333')
INSERT INTO @ContactDetail(ContID, ContType, PhNum, Ext)
VALUES (1, 'Home','44444','X4444')

SELECT ci.ContId
, cd1.ContType ContType1, cd1.PhNum PhNum1, cd1.Ext Ext1
, cd2.ContType ContType2, cd2.PhNum PhNum2, cd2.Ext Ext2
, cd3.ContType ContType3, cd3.PhNum PhNum3, cd3.Ext Ext3
, cd4.ContType ContType4, cd4.PhNum PhNum4, cd4.Ext Ext4
FROM  @ContactInfo ci
INNER JOIN @ContactDetail cd1 ON cd1.ContId = ci.ContId AND cd1.ContType = 'Fax'
INNER JOIN @ContactDetail cd2 ON cd2.ContId = ci.ContId AND cd2.ContType = 'Busn'
INNER JOIN @ContactDetail cd3 ON cd3.ContId = ci.ContId AND cd3.ContType = 'Mobi'
INNER JOIN @ContactDetail cd4 ON cd4.ContId = ci.ContId AND cd4.ContType = 'Home'
```

The basic premise is that each join from @ContactInfo to ContactDetail represents 1 of your types. This will work fine if you only ever have 1 detail entry for each type, if there is any possibility of multiple entries for each type then you will require a different approach.